# Click on a div to activate other div

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I make multiple `<div>` elements with classes or id get active when I press on a `<div>`element that have class or id.
Like the picture below, I want it to go from a white screen to that type of screen that i made with css classes and ids.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tPZou.jpg

You can see the phone I made under here. Press on the black area to get the white screen, I want to press the white to get the passcode screen: https://seigmann123.github.io/iphone12/phone.html

```js
function screen() {
  var e = document.getElementById("screen");
  var c = window.getComputedStyle(e).backgroundColor;
  if (c === "rgb(0, 0, 0)") {
    document.getElementById("screen").style.background = "#ffffff";
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.phone {
  position: relative;
  background: rgb(32, 32, 32);
  border-radius: 30px;
  height: 560px;
  width: 295px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.sensores {
  position: absolute;
  background: rgb(32, 32, 32);
  border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
  height: 32;
  width: 175;
  margin: 0 auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
}

#screen {
  position: absolute;
  background: #000;
  border-radius: 30px;
  height: 540px;
  width: 275px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  top: 10;
}

.off-on-button {
  width: 3px;
  height: 60px;
  background: rgb(32, 32, 32);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 125;
  border-radius: 20px;
  left: 294;
}

.sound-up {
  width: 3px;
  height: 35px;
  background: rgb(32, 32, 32);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 115;
  border-radius: 20px;
  left: -295;
}

.sound-down {
  width: 3px;
  height: 35px;
  background: rgb(32, 32, 32);
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: 160;
  border-radius: 20px;
  left: -295;
}
```

```html
<div class="phone">
  <div id="screen" onclick="javascript:screen();"></div>
  <div class="sensores"></div>
  <div class="off-on-button"></div>
  <div class="sound-up"></div>
  <div class="sound-down"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: What does *"get the passcode screen"* mean? I don't see the layout for **"passcode screen"**.

Comment: I want to make a passcode screen, with multiple <div> elements. so basicly what I want is that I press on the white screen and then the <div> elements get active

Comment: "*I want to make a passcode screen*" then you need to make that screen and add it to the relevant place in your code; "*what I want is that I press on the white screen and then the `<div>` elements get active*" - if they're not present in your HTML they can't be 'active': [edit] your question to update your code to add the content you want/need, once the relevant content is there we can - probably - help with the problem you're having.

Comment: Ok so for one example, I have 3 css Ids,
 `#one {height: 100px;width: 100px;background: blue;}`

`#two {height: 100px;width: 100px; background: red;}`

`#three { height: 100px; width: 100px; background: rgb(0, 235, 59); border-radius: 50%; }`

and first I want to have #one then when I press on #one it get replaced with #two, and when I press #two #three gets on top of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Sample code to mimic what you want to achieve.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Demo</title>
<style>
    #whiteDiv, #blueDiv, #passwd{

        height: 300px;
        width:300px;
    }
    #whiteDiv, #passwd{
        display: none;

    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="border: 1px solid #000;width:300px;height:300px">
    <div style="background-color:#08c" id="blueDiv"onclick="activateWhite();">
        click me
    </div>

    <div style="background-color:#fff" id="whiteDiv" onclick="showPasswd();">
        click me
    </div>
    
    <div style="background-color: #fff;" id="passwd">
        <p>Enter password</p>
        <input type="password">
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    function activateWhite(){
        document.getElementById("whiteDiv").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("blueDiv").style.display = "none";
    }

    function showPasswd(){
        document.getElementById("passwd").style.display = "block";
    }
</script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change JS to

```
  function screen() {
      var e = document.getElementById("screen");
      e.classList.toggle("black-screen")
  }
```

add this to css

```
#screen{
   background:white;
   ...
   ...
 }

.black-screen{
  background:#000 !important;
}
```

Comment: Now i can go from "white-screen" to "screen" is there a way i can do so i only can go from "screen" to "white-screen"?

Answer (score 0):

I can try to explain better and show better.

I want to do so I can press on `#screen` to get `#screen-on`, so then `#screen` gets replaced with `#screen-on`. And when I press on `#screen-on` I want to get `#password-screen` as a overlay on `#screen-on` with `#sircle` on top

```
body{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.phone{
    position: relative;
    background: rgb(32, 32, 32);
    border-radius: 30px;
    height: 560px;
    width: 295px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.sensores{
    position: absolute;
    background: rgb(32, 32, 32);
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
    height:32;
    width: 175;
    margin: 0 auto;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;

}



#screen{
    position: absolute;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 30px;
    height: 540px;
    width: 275px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 10;
    
}


#screen-on{
    position: absolute;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    border-radius: 30px;
    height: 540px;
    width: 275px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 10;
    
}




#sircle{
    width: 65px;
    font-size: 45px;
    line-height: 1.4;
    height: 65px;
    background: #494545;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    bottom: 0px;
    top: 50;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: #dcdcdc;
}

#password-screen {
    position: absolute;
    height: 540px;
    width: 275px;
    background-color: rgb(29, 27, 27);
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    top: 10;
    margin: 0 auto;
    opacity: 0.5;
    border-radius: 30px;
}



.off-on-button{
    width: 3px;
    height: 60px;
    background: rgb(32, 32, 32);
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 125;
    border-radius: 20px;
    left: 294;
}


.sound-up{
    width: 3px;
    height: 35px;
    background: rgb(32, 32, 32);
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 115;
    border-radius: 20px;
    left: -295;
}


.sound-down{
    width: 3px;
    height: 35px;
    background: rgb(32, 32, 32);
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 160;
    border-radius: 20px;
    left: -295;
}
```

Comment: Yes, the code I posted does exactly the same. If you ignore styling, when you click on blue div it activates white div. And then when you click white div it activates password.